# Inserir anuncio a cada 'x' item na lista

Tags: flutter, dart

Boa noite, estou com um pequeno problema em adicionar um anúncio a cada x item da minha lista.

Pesquisando encontrei este pedaço de código

```
void _getData() {
    for (int i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
      var image = ImageClass();

      if (i != 0) {
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
          //Below image.type = "GoogleAds" is Going to the show Ads
          image.type = "GoogleAd";
        } else {
          //Below image.type is Goign to SHow Images
          image.type = "";
          image.images = imageList[i];
        }
        _list.add(image);
      } else {
        image.type = "";
        image.images = imageList[i];
        _list.add(image);
      }
    }
  }
```

Mas como implemento isso em meu código? Já tentei várias soluções e nunca funciona por random. Ou fica em 1 só localização, ou fica repetindo a cada item na lista.

Este é o meu código que reproduz e adiciona o container do ad.

```
Widget adsContainer() {
    return Container(
      height: 250,
      child: NativeAdmob(
       adUnitID: _adUnitID,
        controller: _nativeAdController,
        type: NativeAdmobType.full,
      ),
    );
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
        ListView.builder(
              itemCount: list == null ? 0 : list .length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               return InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            print(list[index].id);
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(text: list[index].id)));
          }, child: Stack(children: [
                  _imageSpace(list[index].image),
                  _colorsSpace(list[index].colors),
                  _nameSpace(list[index].name),
                  _infoSpace(list[index].info),
                ]));
              },
            ),
           adsContainer(), //displaying ad on bottom of everything
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e depois o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer uso da `ListView.separated`, assim fica melhor organizado teu código e mais fácil o entendimento e separação do que é um item da lista e o que é um anúncio.

Vou deixar abaixo um exemplo baseado no que você precisa:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: YellowBird(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class YellowBird extends StatefulWidget {
  const YellowBird({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _YellowBirdState createState() => _YellowBirdState();
}

class _YellowBirdState extends State<YellowBird> {
  final List<int> entries = List.generate(20, (int index) => index);
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: entries.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Container(
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Center(child: Text('Item ${entries[index]}')),
        );
      },
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (index % 5 == 0)
          return Container(
            child: Text("Anúncio aqui"),
            height: 30, 
            color: Colors.red);
        else
          return Container();
      }
    );
  }
}
```

*Você pode testar pelo [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter)*

Comment: Muito obrigado.